# Sql query that checks each GROUPBY or PARTITION BY contains a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that checks to see , for each 'group' in a `GROUP BY` or `PARTITIONS BY`, it contains a value.

/\___ Not a very good way to describe my problem :(

So, I'll give a fake scenario which I just thought up (but it does sound like homework :( even though it's not)

### Problem

- List all the Cages and return a `True` or `False` if the cage has .. say ... a `pug dog`.

#### Scenario

- This is a Pet Shop that sells animals.
- The shop has a number of cages. Each cage has an unique number. Cage `#1`, `#2`, etc.
- Some cages are empty.
- The animals in the cages are either Dogs, Cats or Velociraptor's (whoa! That escalated quickly!!).

.

```
CageID | HasAPugDog
-------------------
1      | False
2      | True
....
```

I wish SqlFiddle was working (it's not) .. so here's a sample schema I quickly whipped up.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cages](
    [CageId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MaxSize] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Cages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CageId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pets](
    [PetId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Breed] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CageId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Pets] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PetId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Pets]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Pets_Cages] FOREIGN KEY([CageId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Cages] ([CageId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Pets] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Pets_Cages]
GO
```

Is the trick to use a `HAVING` statement with a `PARTITION ON` ?

SIDE NOTE: When the lights go out, the security camera has recorded a Cat-wearing-ninja-clothes riding a Velociraptor around the shop.

Comment: what is the relationship between the Cages table and the Pets table?

Comment: Ack! I forgot to include that. Fixed the Table + added FK relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left join, like this:

```
SELECT c.CageID
  , CASE WHEN p.CageID IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END as HasAPugDog
FROM Cages c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CageID 
           FROM Pets
           WHERE Type = 'dog' And Breed = 'pug') p
```

You can also use an EXISTS with a correlated sub-query, but you would get less points for this solutions, as the correlated sub-queries are considered worse in terms of performance:

```
SELECT c.CageID
  , CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Pets p
           WHERE p.CageID = c.CageID and Type = 'dog' And Breed = 'pug') 
        THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END as HasAPugDog
FROM Cages c
```

Comment: Ah! `EXISTS`! I forgot about that.. doh! I've been trying `SUM` with `OVER PARTITION ON`. I'll play around with this...

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the overview per Breed as a table you could use the code below.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (select occupied = CASE WHEN p.CageId = c.CageId THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
         --, p.Type
         , p.Breed
         --, p.CageId
         , c.CageId
    from Cages c
         cross join Pets p) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
    max(occupied) FOR Breed IN ([Pug], [Persian], [Velociraptor Nublarensis])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

Resulting in the following table.

[image: Result]

Comment: Try it. It won't work.

  `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 76
   Incorrect syntax near 'Pug'.`

Comment: Sorry - you're right - you're pivoting - they're column names at that point. Still - your example doesn't work, you can't have a space in the middle of your third column name. I think you can make it work if you wrap it in square brackets though: `IN (Pug, Persian, [Velociraptor Nublarensis])`